# How do I install a specific update of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

I have an install of Visual Studio 2015 community edition that I need to be at update 1. As far as I can tell, I can either have it without any updates or with up to the latest. How do I install version X?

(I'm asking for myself about version 1, but if a general solution is available, that's a better answer)

Comment: why not update to Update 3?

Comment: I agree with @magicandre1981..  these updates are cumulative, so there's no harm in going directly to Update 3 (since Update 3 has all of the fixes from Updates 1-2)

Comment: @egray I would love to just update to #3, but I have some other software that I'm trying to interface with that requires update 1 specifically

Comment: which software requires only the update1?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Some software my company is using. I appreciate that the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/276529) is a thing, but in this circumstance, installing this specific revision of visual studio is the simplest solution, on the face of the actual problem, given that this other software can't be changed, and that software is not relevant to the question.

Comment: are there any incompatibilities when you use the Update 3

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with VS Community Edition, but when I wanted to downgrade from VS Professional 2015 Update 3 to Update 2 (due to [Update 3 screwing with the web.config on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39732135/11912)) and ended up having to uninstall VS 2015 completely, I found [How to: Install a Specific Release of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653628.aspx).

While it covers Enterprise Edition, for VS Professional I just needed to update the name of the installer executable.

So for a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 Professional, with Update 2, run the following from the command line:

```
vs_professional.exe /OverrideFeedURI http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/B/06BB0C5C-C767-4250-91DA-AB463377597E/20160405.3/enu/feed.xml
```